# Is a cost basis on an after tax 401K the money I owe tax on?

Tags: cost-basis

I make after tax contributions to my company 401K.  15 years ago my company didn't offer a ROTH 401K but allowed for after tax contributions. My contributions are 8% of my base pay (after tax) and my company matches 4% of pre-tax dollars.  All interest and reinvested dividends are also pre-tax. My company has switched investment managers and now there is a ROTH 401K option.  If I want to change my 401K to a ROTH 401K, is the cost basis, the money I owe tax on?

Answer (score 2):

Because you invested after-tax dollars, you don't owe tax on those dollars a second time.  The cost basis is the amount you put in.  Therefore, you would owe tax on everything *except* the cost basis.

If your plan allows it, it is obviously to your benefit to convert all your after-tax balance over to Roth, so that future gains will be tax-free unlike your previous plan.  Whether you should also convert some of the tax-deferred balance (gains and match), paying tax in the process, is a much more complicated question.